# Why do VMware Tools not let me enlarge my screen?

Tags: installation, kubuntu, resolution, vmware

I installed a virtual machine using VMware. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and upgraded to Kubuntu 13.10. Works well so far. Then I installed the `vmware-tools` to get a large screen. Seems to install nicely, no errors or nothing, I rebooted but my screen stays small (640x480). How do I get a larger screen?

Comment: Can you get full screen mode?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, full screen works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to drag the vm windows corners, or use a display manager that's installed on the os. For example in Ubuntu it's under "system settings/displays", in KDE you may need to install randr (sudo apt-get install kde-workspace-randr), and then it's under system settings/displays. When you reboot the screen will start small, but upon login it will return to what-ever size you last had it set to.